# I'm creating a small website using angular. In app component l placed <app-navbar>. in browser when I scroll space is coming in top

Tags: html, css, angular

[this is how it looks normaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJl2C.jpg)
[when I scroll up the space is appearing on top of navbar same happens in footer also I user background color in style.css to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrGxW.png)

how to fix the issue. I want the components to be fixed it should not produce the extra space while scrolling

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving `position: absolute;` and `top:0;` for css/scss